# How to eliminate single quote in dynamic sql of SQL server without using replace function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How to eliminate single quote problem in dynamic sql of SQL server without using replace function

ex:

```
 DECLARE @QRY NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
SET @QRY= @QRY + 'SELECT CONCAT(LAST_NAME,'' ''+FIRST_NAME ) as FullName FROM TEST_TABLE'
```

Comment: Why you dont want to use the REPLACE function?

Comment: Right now i have using replace function, if any other ways to replace single quote please suggest.

Comment: What single quote problem? I don't see the problem here... you can replace a space with CHAR(32)

Comment: if you are able to achieve it using the REPLACE function then I dont think there is any other way better way to achieve it.

Comment: Hi MXIX, In my query FIRST_NAME , LAST_NAME COLUMNS data contains single quotes when i concat that columns and solved single quote problem by using replace function. if any other ways do you know, Please suggest

Comment: Oh, do you mean replace of REPLACE ?

Comment: Ya you are correct

Comment: Can you provide simple input & output?

Comment: FIRST_NAME column contains  MA'HE'SH and LAST_NAME column contains PAN'CH'ALA, I need the  data as MAHESH PANCHALA

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query with REPLACE.This will help you if I understand you correctly. This is working fine in SQL Server 2012.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEST_TABLE') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TEST_TABLE
CREATE TABLE #TEST_TABLE 
(
    LAST_NAME nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME nvarchar(200) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO #TEST_TABLE VALUES( 'LastNa''me', 'First''name')
EXEC ('SELECT CONCAT(REPLACE(LAST_NAME,'''''''',''''),'' ''+(REPLACE(FIRST_NAME ,'''''''',''''))) as FullName FROM #TEST_TABLE')
```

Comment: Put `REPLACE` outside of `CONCAT` so that you only have to deal with the apostrophe mess once.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one single quote in your firstname and lastname column, you can try the following solution.

```
CREATE TABLE #Names
    (
      FirstName VARCHAR(30)
    , LastName VARCHAR(30)
    );

INSERT  INTO #Names
        ( FirstName, LastName )
VALUES  ( 'Mah''esh'  -- FirstName - varchar(30)
          , 'Panchala'  -- LastName - varchar(30)
          ),
        ( 'Mah''esh'  -- FirstName - varchar(30)
          , 'Panchal''a'  -- LastName - varchar(30)
          ),
        ( 'Mahesh'  -- FirstName - varchar(30)
          , 'Panchal''a'  -- LastName - varchar(30)
          );

SELECT  *
FROM    #Names;

DECLARE @QRY NVARCHAR(MAX)= '';

SET @QRY = 'SELECT CONCAT(FN.FirstName, '' '', FN.LastName) AS FullName FROM 
             ( SELECT   CASE WHEN PATINDEX(''%''''%'', FirstName) <> 0
                             THEN STUFF(FirstName, PATINDEX(''%''''%'', FirstName),
                                        1, '''')
                             ELSE FirstName
                        END AS FirstName
                      , CASE WHEN PATINDEX(''%''''%'', LastName) <> 0
                             THEN STUFF(LastName, PATINDEX(''%''''%'', LastName),
                                        1, '''')
                             ELSE LastName
                        END AS LastName
               FROM     #Names
             ) FN';
SELECT  @QRY;
EXECUTE (@QRY);
```